# tftpd64.exe crash when booting Debian via PXE

Tags: windows, boot, debian, tftp, netboot

I'm trying to install Debian via PXE with a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit server. I'm using this guide: http://assylias.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/installing-ubuntudebian-with-pxe-using-a-windows-machine/

The client machine successfully loads the Debian installer screen. However, after the installer screen loads on the client, tftpd64.exe crashes with error:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\tftpd\tftpd64.exe
File: .\_gui\gui_dialog.c
Line: 214

Expression: pTftpGui != NULL
```

I've tried both 32- and 64-bit tftpd.exe, and also an old version (3.50).

Is there a way to fix this error, or an alternative way to boot via PXE in Windows?

Comment: From the linked tutorial, it states you can use dhcpsrv instead of tftpd; why not give that a shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a TFTPD32 bug that happens when a client requests many TFTP transfers in a short period of time.

You can try Serva as a TFTPD32 alternative (I'm related to Serva development)